# Dynamodb is not authorised to perform dynamodb:PutItem

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm getting this error while performing PutItem on dynamodb

`AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::8**************2:assumed-role/AmazonSSMRoleForInstancesQuickSetup/i-0**************2 is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:8**************2:table/test-dynamodb-table`

This is how my permissions.yml file look like.

```
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'dynamodb:DescribeTimeToLive'
                  - 'dynamodb:BatchGet*'
                  - 'dynamodb:DescribeStream'
                  - 'dynamodb:DescribeTable'
                  - 'dynamodb:Get*'
                  - 'dynamodb:Query'
                  - 'dynamodb:Scan'
                  - 'dynamodb:BatchWrite*'
                  - 'dynamodb:CreateTable'
                  - 'dynamodb:Delete*'
                  - 'dynamodb:Update*'
                  - 'dynamodb:PutItem'
                Resource:
                  - 'arn:aws:dynamodb:*'
```

I've given all the required permissions but it's still failing. Any help on this??

Comment: Try `arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:*`

Comment: @jellycsc That didn’t work as well:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/iam-policy-example-data-crud.html) if you want to add permission for all DynamoDB tables in all regions for specific account you need to write it like this:

```
"arn:aws:dynamodb:*:123456789012:table/*/"
```

I assume that you can replace account number with * also, but if that is not working you can put your account number.